# PowerMock and JUnit test fails when using isAnnotationPresent

Tags: java

I am trying to test some code that needs the method `method.isAnnotationPresent()`. That thing I do not get running currently, since it always throws me an exception.

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Attempt to create proxy for a non-annotation type.
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.<init>(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:303)
```

In the test itself I just executed the method using that annotation check. There is no magic in there.

The function looks like that:

```
public void checkStuff(String className) {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
    this.filterFancyMethods(Arrays.asList(clazz.getMethods()));
    //More code here
}

private List<Method> filterFancyMethods(List<Method> methods) {
    return methods.stream().filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Fancy.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Annotation:

```
 package de.htw.ai.kbe;

 import java.lang.annotation.*;

 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
 @Documented
 public @interface Fancy {
 }
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void shouldFilterFancyMethods() {
    object.checkStuff("me.neatoro.fancy.testutils.TestClass");
    //Assertations
}
```

Has somebody an idea how to fix that issue?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please add your test code and the declaration of the Fancy interface.

Comment: added some more code

Comment: Looks fine, I guess the exception is caused by your usage of PowerMock. Please post the code where you make use of PowerMock, or even better post your complete code as a gist. (see https://gist.github.com/)